# Cannot run program "...\bin\ffmpeg.exe": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: android, windows, android-ffmpeg

Trying for this Jave program to work on my android where the host is a Windows 64 bit machine. Have created a class and extended FFMPEGLocator class defining the path to the ffmpeg executable in my file system. But doesn't seem to work each time showing "error 13, permission denied". Could someone please put some light into this situation?

> Class extended

```
   class SampleLocator extends FFMPEGLocator {
@Override
protected String getFFMPEGExecutablePath() {
    return "...\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe";
} }
```

> audio converting code

```
File path =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
    File source = new File(url);
    targetFile = new File(path, "sample.wav");
    AudioAttributes audio = new AudioAttributes();
    audio.setCodec("pcm_s16le");
    audio.setBitRate(64000);
    audio.setChannels(2);
    audio.setSamplingRate(44100);
    EncodingAttributes attrs = new EncodingAttributes();
    attrs.setFormat("wav");
    attrs.setAudioAttributes(audio);
    Encoder encoder = new Encoder(new MyDefaultFFMPEGLocator());
    try {
        encoder.encode(source, targetFile, attrs);
       
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException | InputFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   
    } catch (EncoderException e) {
     
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I solved this Permission denied error. You first have to instantiate the ffmpeg executable file instance and then provide the execute permission code pointing the ffmpeg executable file path.
Used the help of this open source project
[ffmpeg-android](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/blob/master/android-ffmpeg/src/main/java/nl/bravobit/ffmpeg/FFmpeg.java)

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod -R 777 " + ffmpeg.getAbsolutePath()).waitFor();
```